# Can't get Phusion Passenger working with Mac OS X Mountain Lion and Apache

Tags: macos, apache2, osx-mountain-lion, osx-server

I just purchased a new Mac mini with Lion Server installed, and immediately upgraded to Mountain Lion Server. I then proceeded to install rvm, rails, Passenger, etc as I've always done (well, the last time I had to install Passenger I was on Snow Leopard).

I followed the instructions found here: http://jasoncodes.com/posts/mac-os-rails-server#ruby

I get no errors when starting/restarting Apache, but the Passenger module doesn't seem to get loaded at all.

Info for Mountain Lion apache is pretty sparse out there, but it looks like a bunch of config files have been moved from /etc/apache2/ into /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2, but I can't figure out what I need to change to have Passenger load.

Comment: Hi, did you get any workaround for this? I am also facing the same issue!!

Answer (score 12):

I faced the same problem while trying to install Redmine on Mountain Lion Server.

The solution was quite simple in my case:

1. install `Xcode` from the AppStore
2. open `Terminal`
3. `sudo gem install passenger`
4. `sudo passenger-install-apache2-module`
5. `sudo nano /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
6. paste the lines the `passenger_module` installer spits out into `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

   LoadModule passenger_module /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.18/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so

   PassengerRoot /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.18

   PassengerRuby /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Version/1.8/usr/bin/ruby

(Make sure you have the correct version number from your installation - mine is 3.0.18)

The point is that in Mountain Lion Server the Server.app has it's httpd config files in

```
/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf
```

However the changes you make to this file are not recognized, to make them permanent you have to edit `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

If you want to use the Passenger Preference Pane you'll have to compile it, as the precompiled version is not compatible with Mountain Lion.

I used the instructions from `redmine.org`:

```
cd ~/Downloads

git clone https://github.com/Fingertips/passengerpane/

cd passengerpane

xcodebuild
```

(If you can't find `xcodebuild`, it may be in `/usr/bin/xcodebuild`)

Install the preference pane. Look in `~/Downloads/passengerpane/build/Release`, and double-click on P`assenger.prefPane` to install it.

Hope this helps..

Cheers!

Comment: Just a small note on step #4 - I was getting missing wrappers error, when trying to compile Apache module, so I had to rvmsudo instead of sudo (rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module).